# Will my web app be deleted if I stop my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

According to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html) "any data stored in the RAM of the host computer or the instance store volumes of the host computer is gone." Does this mean that the web application I installed on my EC2 instance will be deleted if I stop running my instance?

I apologize for the naive question. I am new to this and worried I might make a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An Amazon EC2 instance is just like a normal computer. If you turn it off, anything in RAM is lost. Also, if you reboot either computer, the contents of RAM is lost (well, more like 'forgotten', but effectively the same).

Just like your home computer, if you reboot or stop/start an EC2 instance, it boots up again. Whatever software you have installed on the computer is still there. However, applications you were running will only start if you have configured a startup script to run the app again.

Typically, when software such as a web server is installed on a computer, it is configured to automatically start again when the computer is turned on/rebooted in future.

Elastic Block Store (EBS) disk volumes act just like a disk in a normal computer. If an EC2 instance is stopped and later started again, the contents of the disk is still there, unchanged.

**Bottom line:** It's just like a home computer. Don't panic.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and accessible answer. But because I am paranoid I just want to verify. My application won't be deleted? Once I restart the instance I can run the the app again manually if need be?

Comment: @BenNalle anything on a persistent volume will be available after a reboot or stop/start, but all the same you should plan to be able to restore your app and data from scratch, if needed. That means automation and snapshots.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49183005/4061061), as long as you do not use an [Instance Store volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html), to store your web application, you are good to go.

> The data in an instance store persists only during the lifetime of its
>   associated instance. If an instance reboots (intentionally or
>   unintentionally), data in the instance store persists. However, data
>   in the instance store is lost under the following circumstances:
>
> - The underlying disk drive fails
> - The instance stops
> - The instance terminates

If however you are using an [EBS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonEBS.html) volume, these conditions do not apply and you are free to start and stop your instance any number of times you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes unless you have EBS volume attached to EC2. If you are using an EBS-backed instance, you can stop and restart that instance without affecting the data stored in the attached volume

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, if I attach EBS the web app would be stored on EBS when I stop the instance and reloaded on to the instance when I restart it? Is there a reason I would want to stop the instance? Why wouldn't I just keep the instance running?

Comment: This is entire idea of Elastic. As you need, you can add more and more EC2 instances and stop them when you don't need. You don't need to pay for stopped instances.